# i am trying make function

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am trying make function with Laravel 5 for deleting as  general function i am passing two parameters , first id of post and second the name of class that i wanna delete from, but when i call this function dosnot recognize the the name of class

[image]

and when i put the name manual its work and this the function

```
public function Delete($id,$object){
$single=$object::find($id);    
$single->delete();
  Session::flash('sucess','تم تحديث البيانات بنجاح');   
return redirect()->back();   
}
```

and this the route

```
Route::get('/Delete/{id}/{object}', [
    'uses'=>'admin@Delete',
    'as'=>'Delete'
]);
```

and this the link

```
<a href="{{route('Delete',['id'=>$alls->id,'object'=>'products'])}}"> </a>
```

Comment: If the model is `Product` you should do: `'object' => 'Product'`

Comment: i am sure the model is product and i had tried also this and i have the same error

Comment: its exist and i had worked with the model delete and save and so on

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$single=call_user_func($object.'::find('.$id.'));
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not provide an answer to the question?